# White pixellated blotches when using IES lights

Tags: rendering, lighting

I am trying to render an animated scene using 4 IES spotlights that are shining onto some seats that have a fabric. Can anyone explain why only some pixels of the seats are lit up by the IES spotlights and yet most aren't, creating a tetris style illuminiation?

I have switched off all caustics, the fabric has a roughness of 1.0.

I remain stumped. Any ideas anyone?

[image: see seat fabric pic below]

Comment: Can you tag your question with the renderer, too, please?